# Application width and height declared at one place

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application with several navigation pages. As of now the application height and width is declared in MainWindow and each page.
So here is  MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="My Application"  Height="350" Width="725" >
```

Then each page also has height and width like below

```
<Page x:Class="MyApp.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="725"
    Title="Page1"  >
```

Could there be a one centralized place where I can have height and width, rather having at so many places?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specify width/height as resource in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279732/specify-width-height-as-resource-in-wpf)

Comment: I knew this had to have been asked before.

Comment: That duplicate is not the same question as the close.   Duplicate is size withIN a page.

Comment: @Blam I kind of assumed the OP would be able to notice the nuance difference and figure to put the resource in a resource dictionary and the staticresource in the spots he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Application x:Class="SubSetOf.App"  
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="SysHeight">100</sys:Double>
        <sys:Double x:Key="SysWidth">200</sys:Double>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

<Page x:Class="SubSetOf.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="{StaticResource SysHeight}"
      d:DesignWidth="{StaticResource SysWidth}" 
      Height="{StaticResource SysHeight}" 
      Width="{StaticResource SysWidth}"
      Title="Page1">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Background="pink"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the values as a resource and then bind each page's values to that resource.

Edit:

To save values as a resource, in the properties window under visual studio, click the little box to the right of the text box for width (and height), and select `Convert To New Resource`. There Select `Application Resource` and give the value a name.

In order to use this resource set the values like this:

```
Width = {StaticResource WidthResource}
```

Comment: In your resources: `<System:Double x:Key="StandardHeight">500</System:Double>` then on your view `Width="{StaticResource StandardHeight}"`

Comment: @johnsmith I updated my post with a little more detail on resources

Answer (score 1):

Note that the width and height you see in your `Page` are only for the designer, and are ignored at compile time (by setting the `mc:Ignorable="d"` attribute).

Otherwise you can store the width and height as resources, but I'm not sure that will actually work for the designer