# Wpf ListView with textboxes used as filters

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got listview and for each of it's column a text box. How to attach textbox width to appropriate listview column width?
Example code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="10,41,10,10">
        <ListView.View >
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ASD">
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ASD2">
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ASD3">
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="107,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="200,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Comment: i don't understand your question :D are the `TextBox`s outside of the `ListView`?

Comment: yes, i want to have listview associated with some model. textboxes are suposed to be a filter fields

Comment: What's stopping you from setting the `Width` property for the GridViewColumn?

Comment: Bind the width of the columns to your viewmodel as twoway, and use that property as the binding source for your textbox width...

Comment: user should have got ability to change column width and the filter field should resize automaticly

Comment: If you are using MVVM pattern, do what i told you in my coment and it would work just fine

Answer (score 1):

When you want to bind to the value, you could use this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View >
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="gvc1" Header="ASD" Width="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text}">
            </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="gvc2" Header="ASD2">
            </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="gvc3" Header="ASD3">
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Otherwise:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ASD" Width="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Width}">
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ASD2" Width="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Width}">
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ASD3" Width="{Binding ElementName=textBox2, Path=Width}">
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The other way around

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View >
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="gvc1" Header="ASD">
            </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="gvc2" Header="ASD2">
            </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="gvc3" Header="ASD3">
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=gvc1, Path=Width}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=gvc2, Path=Width}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=gvc3, Path=Width}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I think OP wants the other way around...

Comment: Are you sure your second answer works?? Haven`t tried it, but i'm not sure you can bind to the listview column like that

Comment: Yeah i tried it, it works

Comment: OK..then yours is the simplest way...My +1

Answer (score 0):

You can create a resource in your page which will defined a Width and use this resource in your textbox and your column width.
Here is something that can help you : [Specify width/height as resource in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279732/specify-width-height-as-resource-in-wpf)